# How to set authentication on a specific URL in Jboss eap 6.1.0

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

I am working on a project, where I want to apply authentication on a particular url. 
Jboss Version: Jboss eap 6.1.0

There is an URL in my application
http://localhost:8080/myApp/monitoring
I want when user hit this url, it will ask for user id and password

The below are the steps that I have done

Add following in WEB.XML

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All Access</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/monitoring</url-pattern>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>ApplicationRealm</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/other</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

Then added user using add-user.bat file.
But when I am hitting the url
http://localhost:8080/myApp/monitoring
server is responding back with Error Code 302 and the url is redirecting to 
https://localhost/myApp/monitoring

Can anyone please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misconfigured the `security-constraint` element in `web.xml`.

Try to use following value:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All Access</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/monitoring</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

**And now some details:**

- If you want to protect all HTTP methods accessing given URL, then don't name them in the `web-resource-collection` (otherwise only the named ones are protected)
- If you specify `transport-guarantee` (with value not equal to `NONE`) then you de facto requests using **`https`** (SSL/TLS) instead of **`http`**
- You have to provide `auth-constraint` (with list of roles to which you grant access) if you don't want to grant access to everyone